# Neo4j/Cypher dense node match result ordering

Tags: neo4j, cypher, graph-databases, nosql

I have a `(:User)` dense node with following relationships:

```
(:User)-[:SUBSCRIBED]->(:User)
(:User)-[:CONNECTED]->(:SocialNetwork)
```

If I execute query below

```
MATCH (u:User {UserId:id})
MATCH (u)-[:SUBSCRIBED]->(s)
RETURN s
```

I get user's subscribers ordered by recent which is expected.

But the same query with additional matching pattern brakes this ordering

```
MATCH (u:User {UserId:id})
MATCH (u)-[:SUBSCRIBED]->(s)
OPTIONAL MATCH (s)-[:CONNECTED]->(sn)
RETURN s, COUNT(sn.FriendCount)
```

Could someone explain why ordering by recent doesn't work in the second example.

Answer (score 1):

There is no guarantee of order in your query because you don't have an `ORDER` clause, run the same query 1000 times and I'm sure the order will change at some point.

You should order at the end of the query :

```
MATCH (u:User {UserId:id})
MATCH (u)-[:SUBSCRIBED]->(s)
OPTIONAL MATCH (s)-[:CONNECTED]->(sn)
RETURN s, COUNT(sn.FriendCount)
ORDER BY s.time // ? property representing the time
```

Comment: first query always ordered by recent for dense nodes

Comment: Even for dense nodes you don't have guarantee of ordering without an explicit `ORDER` clause